# Google Cloud Endpoints v2: Any way to inject User?

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I'm new to Google Cloud Endpoints and I am currently looking for an alternate way to receive the `User` method parameter.

In the documentation on [Authenticating Users](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/authenticating-users), the **only** way of receiving information about the user that is shown is to receive an instance `com.google.api.server.spi.auth.common.User` as a method parameter.

There appears to be no annotation I can use to request this principle elsewhere other than directly on the endpoint method. This can obviously be made to work, but I am very interested in the following scenario:

```
/*
 * in an injection provider
 */
CustomUserClass getUser(@EndpointsUser User user) throws UnauthorizedException{
    if(user == null) throw new UnauthorizedException("If we're requesting the user be injected, we should reject unauthenticated requests");
    //datastore code to lookup and return my representation of a user
}

/*
 * in the endpoint class
 */
@Inject
CustomUserClass userProfile;

//endpoint methods here
```

Does anyone know how to do the above? I realize I could simply move this logic into my endpoint class, but this is a case of cross-cutting concerns and is not only bad programming, but less easily tested.

Yes, I know I can role my own solution (pun intended), but cloud endpoints is supposed to make this kind of thing easy, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible, as Guice use cases weren't common when the frameworks were written. You can [file a feature request](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/endpoints-java).